# How to create pop up in fragment without using Fragment that doesn't support v4?

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup, fragment

**MainMenu.Java**

```
    public class MainMenu extends Activity { 

    Button createConfluenceButton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createConfluenceButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.create_confluence);
        createConfluenceButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                TEACHER_AddConfluence teacher_add_confluence = new TEACHER_AddConfluence();
                //ERROR IN HERE
                teacher_add_confluence.show(getFragmentManager(), "TEACHER_AddConfluence");
                }
        });
    }

}
```

**TEACHER_AddConfluence.java**

```
    public class TEACHER_AddConfluence extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate( seamolec.ujianonline.R.layout.teacher_add_course_material, container, false);
        getDialog().setTitle("DialogFragment Tutorial");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I want to display pop up in fragment. **I don't use Fragment which support v4 so I don't extend FragmentActivity.** 
Because I use standards Fragment, I get error in this line in **MainMenu.java**

```
TEACHER_AddConfluence teacher_add_confluence = new TEACHER_AddConfluence();
//ERROR IN HERE
teacher_add_confluence.show(getFragmentManager(), "TEACHER_AddConfluence");
```

**I can't call method getSupportFragmentManager() because I don't extends FragmentActivity or doesn't use fragment that support v4**

How to create pop up in standard fragment ?

Comment: what error you are getting in `teacher_add_confluence.show` line ?

Comment: Method show can't be used because I use getFragmentManager() not getSupportFragmentManager(). It should be getSupportFragmentManager() but because I don't use fragment that support v4 or extend FragmentActivity. I can't use getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are importing `DialogFragment` fragment from `support v4` but passing `getFragmentManager()` in `DialogFragment.show`  method.

Import DialogFragment from  `android.app` package:

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```